# Run tab disappeared in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

In one of my projects the `Run` tab on the bottom of the screen disappeared recently in IntelliJ Ultimate. When I run the project `Services` tab opens by default.

[image]

`Run` doesn't present in `View` -> `Tool Windows` neither.

[image]

If I open another project `Run` tab is there.
[image]

Any ideas how to make it back ?

Comment: Please open "Run/Debug Configurations" dialog, select "Templates" and check "Configurations Available in Services" list.

Comment: There was `Spring Boot` in the list. After I removed it `Run` tab came back. Thanks

Comment: Use `⌘4` to Show/Hide the Run tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **y.bedrov** suggested in the comment to the question I checked Run/Debug Configurations and found in the list `Spring Boot` option. After I removed it `Run` tab came back.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try to delete the .idea-folder and re-import the project (e.g. from pom.xml). Maybe you IDE got confused because of updated plugins.